# Add Angular 2 to an older JHipster project with Angular 1 already

Tags: angular, jhipster

Having a JHipster application with a client side app written in Angular 1. Is there a way to add to add Angular 2 to the current project? I wouldn't generate an entirely new project for Angular 2.

Comment: [angular guide for upgrading](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)

Comment: @Arkey Jhipster has a different structure for client-side app than a simple angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit your `.yo-rc.json` file and set `"clientFramework": "angularX",` then delete `src/main/webapp` and re-generate your app with `jhipster --with-entities`